# I have to extract data from SQL Server and dump it in Oracle Client

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have to extract data(some specific fields not the entire database) from SQL Server and dump it in Oracle Client.Now I have been able to extract data from SqlServer using SqlDataAdaptor and DataSet.But after this how do I connect to Oracle to insert the values into the Oracle database.

I have seen linked servers but my boss wants me to send data directly to oracle.
Could some one help me out.

The code snippet for first is ->

```
SqlDataAdapter o_SQLDataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter("select TOP 10 POSITION_ID, POSITION_DESC  from T_CD_POSITION", conn);

conn.Open();

//create and intialize a dataset object
DataSet o_ds_retrievedData = new DataSet();

//fill the data into dataset according to SQL query provided to adaptor
o_SQLDataAdaptor.Fill(o_ds_retrievedData, "T_CD_POSITION");

conn.Close();

//display results: loop through dataset as datarow object to present one row per loop
Console.WriteLine("Positon ids and description  for the table RD2K");

Console.WriteLine("...............................................");

foreach (DataRow tempRow in o_ds_retrievedData.Tables["T_CD_POSITION"].Rows)
{
            Console.WriteLine(tempRow["POSITION_ID"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(tempRow["POSITION_DESC"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: So your boss doesn't want you to just establish a direct link from SQL Server to Oracle and perform the insert across that?

Comment: @David Aldridge No,he doesn't want that. But still how do I establish a direct link from SQL Server to Oracle.

Comment: Erm ... did it about two years ago as a one-off, but I was consulting docs and Googling as I went so no chance of remembering. It can't be uncommon though, so have a google around. This method that your boss wants you to use -- looks awful. Look for another job while you're Googling.

Comment: Can you use an SSIS package? Also, if this needs to be repeatable, highly recommend you use the Oracle client not the M$ client for Oracle.

Comment: I din get you for the last part and No, I might not use SSIS package

Comment: I have used data table to extract data from sql server and oracle database. So , now I have to send data from one data table to other. Is there any function used to map two data tables from two different databases(In this case Sql server and Oracle) @DavidAldridge

Comment: Sorry, I've got no idea. It sounds awful though.